# How to prevent users from accessing files on server?

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, file

I have an application that let users to upload files to server. All files are stored in one directory called `Uploaded Files` (which has `Thumbnails` directory inside).

What are the most common ways for preventing users to see these files ? I mean I don't want users to see the files by typing URL like `/path_to_website/Uploaded Files/1.png`.

On the other side, authorized users should be able to see the files by getting a page that contains paths to files, like: `../Uploaded Files/1.JPG`, `../Uploaded Files/2.png`, `../Uploaded Files/3.gif`. These users should be able to see only the files that appear on the page they got, i.e. I want to prevent them to see `../Uploaded Files/823.gif` for example.

Please help to understand how this kind of things are done these days.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to protect downloadable files in a remote directory from non-premium users (in php?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550071/how-to-protect-downloadable-files-in-a-remote-directory-from-non-premium-users-i)

Comment: Here's a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416736/how-to-password-protect-files-images-video-zip-dynamically-from-public-and-al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the images into a folder out side the public directory and then stream them in via PHP to the users who are allowed to view them. By using the method detailed in the PHP [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manual for a very basic output (see Example 1).

Otherwise you could put a .htaccess file in the folder containing:

```
deny from all
```

if you are running Apache, but you still need to stream it out through PHP.